# send and receive data to web service through Android

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-service, development-environment

i'm trying to build an android app which sends login details to SOAP 1.1 web service(C#) and gets employee details. i'm using ksoap2 v2.3 lib and developing for gingerbread version v2.3 of android. suggest me with the form of data the web service should return and which form i should choose to retrieve the data and save it to my local SQLite db?

Comment: You have post your own code here.

Comment: If you want to send your data to server then use ArrayList<NamepairValues> for add parameters to url and then use HTTPPOST method. And after post data the id which u are getting just get using json parsing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works is that you have to upload your web services on a server. Try 000webhost.com

Than you can use the URL of the web service to connect/send data/recieve data from the web service

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

this might help you